# compile raw .rsc file into my iPhone app

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, embedded-resource, palm-os

I am porting an app from palm to iPhone OS
and would like to use .rcs files from palm port.
These files contain large amount of raw hex constatnts, that have to be hard - coded into app.
When I try to compile my .rcs file in xCode, compile goes successfully.
Does this mean I can embed these files into app and access the data?
If yes - please direct me on how to embed and access these data from within the app.

the file format is something like (but much larger):

HEX "data" ID MyMinValueRcs
    0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
    0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
    0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
    0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0

HEX "data" ID MyMaxValueRcs
    0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
    0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 
    0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0

Answer (score 0):

The PilRC compiler used to process .rcp files for Palm OS will by default output a series of .bin files.  These are the raw binary resources.  You can use that to compile your HEX data into a dataID.bin file which you could then use in your project.  I'm not sure how to pull in that bin file in XCode, but it's probably easier to link that in than have a script convert the HEX source files.